# Magento 2 SSH CLI reindexing not working

Tags: magento2, database, ssh, php-7.3, magento2.3.6

I just installed a Magento 2.3.6 version. and I tried to run the Command Reindexing but it's not working. I tried with diff commands like cache clear and flush none of the commands are not working through SSH. How can i achieve this thing. Can anyone help me with it please.[image: Please Look at the Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I Think the issue is with file permissions run the below commands, it will help you to get out of the issue

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media  generated/ app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media generated/ app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Then Run

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: None of the above comments work. It's behaving like same before. When ever i run the command CLI is not responding to it. It's just goes to next line itself.

Comment: https://www.magemonkeys.com/magento-2-commands-not-working-after-upgrade-to-latest-version/ go through this link

Comment: Broo, It tried it as mentions in magemonkeys but still im facing the same issue. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2621440 bytes) in /home/towercirclestore/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/MySQL/Definition/Index.php on line 54

It is showing the above error

Comment: Just add this line before the line where you get error in your php file--->
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: Tried it broo, Still facing the issues here